# Javascript get name of instance of class

Tags: javascript, class

```
function myClass(a,b,c) {
     this.alertMyName=function(){alert(instancename)}

{...}


}
```

and then

```
foo = myClass(a,b,c);
boo = myClass(a,b,c);

foo.alertMyName(); //it should alert 'foo'
boo.alertMyName(); //it should alert 'boo'
```

In practice I'll need it for class that is creating a lot of html objects to prefix their ID's to differentiate them from same object created by another instance of this class.

Comment: You can pass instance name as parameter or use `this`.

Comment: alert(this) returns [object Object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to David's answer, variables in javascript have a value that is either a primitive or a reference to an object. Where the value is a reference, then the thing it references has no idea what the "name" of the variable is.

Consider:

```
var foo = new MyThing();
var bar = foo;
```

So now what should `foo.alertMyName()` return? Or even:

```
(new MyThing()).alertMyName();
```

If you want instances to have a name, then give them a property and set its value to whatever suits.

Answer (score 9):

I Couldn't find a solution on Stack Overflow so here is a solution I found from [ronaldcs](http://www.dforge.net/author/ronaldcs/)    on dforge.net: 
[http://www.dforge.net/2013/01/27/how-to-get-the-name-of-an-instance-of-a-class-in-javascript](http://www.dforge.net/2013/01/27/how-to-get-the-name-of-an-instance-of-a-class-in-javascript/)/

```
myObject = function () {
  this.getName = function () {
    // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
    for (var name in window)
      if (window[name] == this)
        return name;
  };
};
```

Try it Out:

```
var o = new myObject(); 
alert(o.getName()); // alerts "o"
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer hasn't received much attention.

Comment: This works like a champ in a class.  Note: The value returned will be the first variable name assigned when an object is instantiated - For example, var a=new foo(); var b=a; var c=b; console.log(c.getName()); //Displays "a"

Answer (score 4):

You could bring it in as a parameter:

```
function myClass(name, a, b, c) {
   this.alertMyName = function(){ alert(name) }
}

foo = new myClass('foo', a, b, c);
```

Or assign it afterwards:

```
function myClass(a, b, c) {
   this.setName = function(name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   this.alertMyName = function(){ 
       alert(this.name)
   }
}

foo = new myClass( a,b,c);
foo.setName('foo');
```

Comment: is it really the only way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, you can’t get a string "representation" of any variable in javascript, partly because it could be a reference to another object.

Comment: There are other ways, but they are essentially the same.