# How to get the instance name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, instance

If I create a class like this:

```
function MyClass(input){
  // construct something;
  var myInstanceName = ???
}
```

I'll need the name of the instance when creating an instance...

var MyInstance = new MyClass("Make Something");

Need to know myInstanceName (="MyInstance" in this case) because there is a method that creates buttons and the "onclick" must call a method of this instance.

I tried "this.name" but it returns undefined... How do I get this value?

EDIT: Here is a tested working example:

```
function MyClass(WhereGoesTheButton){
    this.myName = "Test"; // <-- here is the issue
    this.idButton = WhereGoesTheButton;
    //
}
MyClass.prototype.createButton = function(){
    document.getElementById(this.idButton).innerHTML = '<button id="myId" onclick="'+this.myName+'.callBack(this);">Press Here</button>';
}
MyClass.prototype.callBack = function(who){
    alert("Button "+who.id+" has been pressed!");
}
var Test = new MyClass("testArea");
//
function ini(){
    Test.createButton();
}
```

Just put it in a page with body onload ini() and some div to create the button.

It works, but alternatives with better practices are welcome!

EDIT 2: this will do the job, although we still got no name of the instance:

```
var MyClassId = 0;
function MyClass(WhereGoesTheButton){
    this.myButtonId = "MyClass"+String(MyClassId);
    MyClassId++;
    this.idButton = WhereGoesTheButton;
    //
}
MyClass.prototype.createButton = function(){
    var me = this;
    document.getElementById(this.idButton).innerHTML = '<button id="'+this.myButtonId+'" >Press Here</button>';
    document.getElementById(this.myButtonId).addEventListener("click", function(e){ me.callBack(this); }, false);
}
MyClass.prototype.callBack = function(who){
    alert("Button "+who.id+" has been pressed!");
}
var Test = new MyClass("testArea");
//
function ini(){
    Test.createButton();
}
```

Comment: If you need to know the name of the variable, you are 99.99% of the time doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: What if I'm 0.01% ??? Ok, an alternative way of doing the same thing is welcome. In AS3 I get the variable by "target" property of the event, but it seams there isn't such thing in JS...

Comment: Check out my answer to this duplicate question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972262/javascript-get-name-of-instance-of-class/23294728#23294728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need to know myInstanceName (="MyInstance" in this case) because there is a method that creates buttons and the "onclick" must call a method of this instance.

Why do you need the variable name for that? Your method can reference the current instance with `this`.

However, inside a click handler `this` will be the clicked element. Assuming you're bind the event somewhat like this:

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', this.someMethod, false);
```

... you can change it to:

```
var that = this;
someElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    that.someMethod()
}, false);
```

There are other possible solutions too, like [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and the [`EventListener` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener).

Comment: As described, the class create some buttons in the page, when clicked, it must call a method of the instance of the class that created those buttons. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @GustavoPinent Yes, there is another way. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I think this way is better, however, unfortunately, it doesn't work because I got to identify the button with a unique ID so I can use addEventListener on it. Maybe a trick is numbering as instances are been created, but with the name of the instance will be easier, I think.

Comment: @GustavoPinent how are you binding the click event?

Comment: I'm not using bind, not sure if will work and may not be accepted by older browsers. But your suggestion is almost right! I did a numbering (will be above) and now it works. In the future, "this.name" will do the job, but right now we got only the hack.

Answer (score 5):

Simple code example:

```
 function Parent(){
        // custom properties
    }

    Parent.prototype.getInstanceName = function(){
        for (var instance in window){
            if (window[instance] === this){
                return instance;
            }
        }
    };

    var child = new Parent();

    console.log(child.getInstanceName()); // outputs: "child"
```

Comment: It seams will work only if the instance were created in the root. Also, might slow down if got to look at all window objects. But it's interesting, I will keep this code near...

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what i have been searching for! =)

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance when inside the constructor. However, note well that in Javascript, `this` is determined dynamically *when a function is called*. So if you are eg. setting up handlers using `this` in a constructor without judicious use of `bind`, you will likely run into errors.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) for more info on `this`

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion if you really need the name, just pass it as an optional argument in the constructor. Then if provided can set a member property `this.instanceName = passedNameArgument` then access it later for error handling or whatever your needs are.