# Function changing the "this" variable

Tags: javascript, this

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to get my head around some of the fundamentals of OOP and simulated "classes". 
Upon executing the final line of this script, I would like the invoked `this` object pointer on line 4 to refer to the `farm` object (just like it correctly does in line 2 and 3).

Unfortunately it does not, and I would guess that the `this` object pointer is instead pointing towards `document`.

```
var Building = function(cost){
    this.cost = cost;
    this.printCost = function(){
        document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = this.cost;
    }
}

var farm = new Building (50);

farm.printCost();
```

-

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="farm">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get this function to use right object? If there are any errors in my understanding please let me know.

I'm not yet familiar with jQuery so if you could stick to core JavaScript syntax I'd appreciate it!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7n2of9k7/

Comment: `getElementById(this)' would never work regardless

Comment: Why not just pass `farm` as a string to function?

Comment: Just pass it in as a string: `... = function(cost, element)` where element is the element to insert into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, getting the instance's variable name as a string is impossible. I also really don't see why you would would do this as it's quite impractical. I would just pass in the element you want inserted into as a string:

```js
var Building = function(cost, element){
    this.cost = cost;
    this.printCost = function(){
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = this.cost;
    }
}

var farm = new Building(50, 'farm');

farm.printCost();
```

```html
<p id="farm">
</p>
```

This now just passes an ID into the function so it inserts correctly. You can also pass this to `printCost`.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! This works perfectly and has cleared up a lot of confusion for me! I think I was trying to automate _too_ much.

Answer (score 2):

**"THIS "** inside a method of constructor function always indicate the instance of that constructor function ,in your case **this==farm**.You are passing the whole object instance inside `getElementById()` method.Change your printCost method to get the name of the object instance which matches **this**.You need to iterate over window object which will have all the variables defined in it's scope.**So your object will be to get the variable name from window object which matches the name of the name of the variable "farm"**. Then use it in `getElementById()` .[check this answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972262/javascript-get-name-of-instance-of-class)

```
this.printCost = function(){
    for(var prop in window){
       if(window[prop]==this){
           document.getElementById(prop).innerHTML = this.cost;
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: i mean it will after creating the instance ofcourse.That what op is doing :)

Comment: That's weird. Could you post a fiddle?

Answer (score -4):

You have to assign this to variable, and use it on your anonymous

```
function
    var Building = function(cost){
    this.cost = cost;
    var currentObj = this;
    this.printCost = function(){
        document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = currentObj.cost;
    }
}

var farm = new Building (50);

farm.printCost();
```

Comment: This is completely invalid. Why is there a function keyword before a variable declaration? `var Building = function(cost) { ... }` is perfectly valid.